# why this error : no function for call to 'Class11::Class11( )'

Tags: c++

why the code below show an error : no function for call to 'Class11::Class11()'
how can I fix this without modifying the main function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Class1
{
public:
    void display()
    {

    }
};
class Class11 :public Class1
{
    int m;
public:
    Class11(int x){m=x;}
    void setValue(int x)
    {
        m=x;
    }
};
int  main()
{
    Class1 *ptr;
    Class11 obj, obj2(1102);
    obj.setValue(1203);
    ptr = &obj;
    ptr->display();
    ptr = &obj2;
    ptr->display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are default constructing a `Class11` instance caller `obj` here:

```
Class11 obj, obj2(1102);
        ^^^
```

Since `Class11` has a user defined constructor, the compiler does not generate a default one. You need to provide `Class11`'s  default constructor yourself:

```
public:
  Class11() : m(0) {}  // default ctor
  Class11(int x){m=x;}
```